# Android Title + Button in titlebar not coming properly aligned

Tags: android, button, title, titlebar

I am trying to add title + button in titlebar in Android. But somehow i am not happy with the kind of result i am getting. May be something wrong with code. Has anyone tried this earlier ? My .xml is below

code.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="#484848"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Support"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="30sp" ></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/syncbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Sync" />

       </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How exactly you want your titlebar to look like.Please add image

Comment: @Manishika - It is as shown in picture just that i am not able to do proper alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your XML with below code..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#484848"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Support"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="30sp" ></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/syncbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


            android:text="Sync" />

       </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this work.....

Comment: Thanks Arvind for your effort but it is giving the same result :(

Answer (score 2):

Please mention exact issue you are facing, I assume the alignment of the two views is not proper is the issue.
You can give the relative position of the button with respect to the text view to the button xml,

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/windowtitle"
```

Also, add the alignment to the textview

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="#484848">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Support"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="30sp" ></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/syncbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Sync" />

       </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my screen

[image]

Comment: @Tamilian we are very close. I posted screenshot in question again. The button is not yet properly aligned

Comment: @user45678 add this line `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in button it must work and also remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: M talking about your code only. I posted the screenshot in question. Check that again. The button is not coming in center

Comment: I am using the same code which u mentioned and it is giving me result as i posted in second screenshot. Everything is working fine only if you can observe button is not in center, it is little up. I tried "layout:margin_Top" but it won't work. The button should be little in the center

Comment: @user45678 remove margin

Comment: @user45678 check out my scrren shot

Comment: Ohh man...How come this much difference ? But really thanks for your help...much appreciated

Comment: Nop...I am not sure some other factors should be affecting. I am checking. Let me see...I will get back shortly

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` from  **windowtitle** Textview and add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` even change width to `wrap_content`.

and add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to **syncbutton** button and there is no need of `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

It all centered your views.

check below xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#484848"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textSize="30sp" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/syncbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Sync" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="#484848" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Support"
        android:textSize="30sp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/syncbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Sync" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="#484848"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Support"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="30sp" ></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/syncbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:text="Sync" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code this might fullfill your requirement:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#484848"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Support"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="30sp" ></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/syncbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"            
            android:text="Sync" />

       </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```